# ssh session hijacking

Tags: ssh

I've created a simple scenario with ssh session hijacking. There is single session open from host A to host B and I can create another connection inside of established connection.
I'm wondering how to detect in a SIEM such an activity?I can't use ports because there is only one normal ssh connection.

Any ideas?

Comment: How can you *create another connection inside of established connection*? Do you mean ssh tunneling?

Comment: I believe he means [ssh session multiplexing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing), the ability to run multiple ssh sessions over a single TCP connection

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, if you want to detect when a new multiplexed session is opened over an existing SSH connection you will not be able to detect it at the network level, as the multiple sessions are multiplexed over a single TCP connection.

To be able to record the additional sessions you need to increase the SSH server log level, changing `LogLevel` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` from the default `INFO` to `VERBOSE` will record the following entries when a new session is established over an existing connection:

**Running a command**

```
Oct 13 19:02:32 server sshd[18850]: Starting session: command for myuser from 192.168.0.1 port 48196 id 1
Oct 13 19:02:32 server sshd[18850]: Close session: user myuser from 192.168.0.1 port 48196 id 1
```

**Opening an interactive shell**

```
Oct 13 19:11:10 server sshd[19379]: Starting session: shell on pts/5 for myuser from 192.168.0.1 port 48196 id 1
```

Note how the port does not change for the various sessions, while the `id` number identifies each separate session.

In summary: Increase the log level for sshd, then feed the ssh server logs to your SIEM and look for the appropriate log entries.

Comment: I've tested your recommendation and it's working flawlessly!thank you